# Installing Semicode OS on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, operating-system, virtualbox

Has anyone installed SemiCode OS on VirtualBox? Can you please share how you did it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Virtualbox and click “New”
- Enter Name (SemicodeOS or anything else you want)
- Choose Type - Linux and version - Ubuntu (32-bit)  -> Continue (The 64-bit -  version hasn’t yet been released.)
- Allocate 512MB+ memory (preferably 1024MB+) -> Continue
- Check “Create a virtual hard disk now” -> Continue
- VDI (VirtualBox Disk Image) -> Continue
- Check “Dynamically allocated” -> Continue
  Allocate Disk size -> Create.
- Now Choose SemicodeOS (or whatever name you picked) from the list of virtual  machines (Left pane) and Start.
- Click the browse icon (small folder icon to the right of the select menu) on the Popup window that appears when the VM runs.
- Browse to where you downloaded/stored the SemicodeOS-dist.iso file, Open and Start
- Enjoy!

Comment: This is incorrect, semicode os doesn't work for virtualbox.